# Error al importar "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package" PYTHON

Tags: python

Soy un poco novato aun en Python , ya que estoy empezando su aprendizaje. Me he encontrado con un problema a la hora de hacer un "import" bastante basico. He buscado informacion en Google , pero no entiendo muy bien las soluciones que he visto , por eso recurro a vuestra sabiduria.

El error es el siguiente ;

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Users/usuario/Desktop/miproyecto/hello.py", line 4, in <module>
from .forms import LoginForm # importamos login
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Bien , la carpeta de mi proyecto tiene la siguiente estructura :

[image: Estructura]

Y este es el codigo de mi archivo Hello.py ;

```
from flask import Flask  # Creamos objeto flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect # Creamos objeto 
plantilla , flash , etc
from .forms import LoginForm # importamos login


app.config.from_object('config') # Leemos configuracion creada

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def hello_world():
 return 'Hello, World!'



@app.route('/templates')
 def templates():
  user = {'nickname': 'juan'} 
  return render_template('index.html',
                       title='Home',
                       user=user)


# index view function suppressed for brevity

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
form = LoginForm()
return render_template('login.html',
                       title='Sign In',
                       form=form)
```

Y este el de mi archivo forms.py ;

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField 
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class LoginForm(Form):
openid = StringField('openid', validators=[DataRequired()])
remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano! Un saludo!

Comment: En SO requerimos el código como texto, no como imagen, lee [ask] :-)

Comment: Perdon! Ya lo he corregido :)

Comment: ¿cual es el mensaje de error?, por favor no parafrasees el mensaje de error, copialo y pegalo en tu pregunta tal como se muestra.

Comment: Listo. Gracias!